# JSP page to PHP page convertion?

Tags: java, php, javascript

I want to know that there is any solution to convert JSP pages to PHP pages.
Because I required these PHP  pages to be integrate into Joomla.it is compulsion to use Joomla.There is no alternative to joomla.Hence we stucked to this conversion problem.So,we require any convertor or any alternative to convert JSP pages PHP page.

Comment: Nope, two completely different languages.

Comment: These languages are miles apart in both how they approach a solution to a web page and the "preferred" way to do it.  You'll likely be stuck with a complete rewrite.

Comment: Why can't you have a java bridge ?

Comment: You'll probably need to convert them all manually, since JSPs can contain calls to arbitrary Java code. Not going to be fun (especially if the calls use Java libraries that don't have PHP equivalents).

Comment: You can run Apache Tomcat with Apache HTTPd (Jakarta Connector) so you could run both PHP & JSP, but this is more a patch. Could be useful for projects transitions for example!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no reliable convertor apart from a human programmer that knows both languages. JSP and PHP are too far apart (not just the languages, also the APIs and libraries that you'll use with them) to make any kind of automatic conversion possible.
Any attempt to do so would require more programmer time to clean up the result than a complete rewrite in PHP.